# Use conditional xpath to get values from html

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to extract some values from an Excel. I'm using a bespoke software which converts the excel in to an html code set. I have to extract some details which actually change the location according to the layout of the document. Below is a small part of one type of a layout,

```
<td data-cell="D10">ORDER #</td>
<td data-cell="E10" colspan="9">SO-10415</td>
<td data-cell="N10"">DATE OF</td>
<td data-cell="O10"rowspan="2">18.01.2021</td>
```

And this is another layout type,

```
<td data-cell="A20" colspan="3">SO Number : SO0010810</td>
<td data-cell="D20" colspan="2"></td>
```

So I need to do a conditional check like,

```
if(contains(.,'ORDER #'))
 then following-sibling::td[1]
 else contains(.,'SO Number')/@storedvalue
```

Above is not correct I'm just trying to give you guys an idea what I've trying to do. I tried many ways mentioned in SO and in other sites. Below are few code lines I tried but none of them worked.

```
1. //tr/td[if(contains(.,'ORDER #')) then following-sibiling::td[1] else contains(.,'SO Number')]

2. //tr/td[concat(substring('ORDER', 1, number(text()='ORDER ') * string-length('ORDER')) substring('SO Number', 1, number(not(text()='ORDER') )* string-length('So Number')))]

3. //tr/td[concat(substring('ORDER #', 1, number(text()='ORDER #') * string-length('ORDER #'))]

4. (//tr/td[text()='ORDER #']/following-sibling::td[1] )| (//tr/td[not(text()='ORDER #')/@storedvalue])
```

Actual part of the generated code after excel run through the document mapper.

**Layout type 1**

```
<tr style="height:22px;">
<td style="padding:0 2px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:bottom;">10</td>
<td data-cell="A10" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">BILL TO:</td>
<td data-cell="B10" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="D10" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">ORDER #</td>
<td data-cell="E10" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:16px;font-weight:700;text-align:center;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="9">SO-10415</td>
<td data-cell="N10" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">DATE OF</td>
<td data-cell="O10" style="mso-number-format:'M/D/YY';border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;font-weight:700;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" rowspan="2">18.01.2021</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:21px;">
<td style="padding:0 2px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:bottom;">11</td>
<td data-cell="A11" style="border-color:#000;border-left:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">MSFT MCIO Limited</td>
<td data-cell="B11" style="border-color:#000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="D11" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="E11" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="F11" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="G11" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="H11" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="I11" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="J11" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="K11" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="L11" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="M11" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="N11" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;font-family:Calibri Light;font-size:11px;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">NOTE:</td>
</tr>
```

**Layout type 2**

```
<tr style="height:29px;">
<td style="padding:0 2px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:bottom;">19</td>
<td data-cell="A19" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="3">Moss Lane Manchester, M45 8FJ</td>
<td data-cell="D19" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="E19" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td><td data-cell="F19" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="G19" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">LON22</td>
<td data-cell="H19" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="I19" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="J19" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="K19" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
<td data-cell="L19" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:21px;"><td style="padding:0 2px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:bottom;">20</td>
<td data-cell="A20" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="3">SO Number : SO0010810</td>
<td data-cell="D20" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="2"></td>
<td data-cell="F20" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="2">MSPO# 80272185</td>
<td data-cell="H20" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="2">Incoterms : DDP</td>
<td data-cell="J20" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="3">Mode of Transport : Air Freight</td></tr><tr style="height:22px;"><td style="padding:0 2px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:bottom;">21</td>
<td data-cell="A21" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="3">Ship Date : 23/02/2021</td>
<td data-cell="D21" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="4">Sales Contact : NIAMH CULLEN</td>
<td data-cell="H21" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="3">Inbound I.D<span style="font-size:16px;"> </span></td>
<td data-cell="K21" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="2">Currency :  GBP £</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:21px;"><td style="padding:0 2px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:bottom;">22</td>
<td data-cell="A22" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">Line Item </td>
<td data-cell="B22" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-left:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;text-align:center;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="2">Part Number</td>
<td data-cell="D22" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;text-align:center;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" colspan="4">Description </td>
<td data-cell="H22" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;text-align:center;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">COO</td>
<td data-cell="I22" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;text-align:center;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">HTS Code</td>
<td data-cell="J22" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;text-align:center;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">Quantity</td>
<td data-cell="K22" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;text-align:center;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">Unit Price</td>
<td data-cell="L22" style="border-color:#000;border-top:medium solid #000000;border-bottom:medium solid #000000;border-right:medium solid #000000;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:700;text-align:center;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">Total</td>
</tr>
```

**Desired output**

So desired out is to get the values of where it contains "ORDER #" or "SO Number". If the word is "ORDER #" then I want to get the values of the next cell, which is "SO-10415". Else get the values of the cell which contains "SO Number" and in current case it would be "SO Number : SO0010810". So it should be like below.

```
If word contain (or equal) "ORDER #" output should be SO-10415.
If word contain (or equal) "SO Number" output should be SO Number : SO0010810.
```

And I think the software is using xpath v 1.0 not 2.0. But I do prefer to have a solution that would fit both versions, if possible but either would be accepted. I tried to build a solution after reading more posts here but still have no success.

Comment: Can you post a complete (small) XML file, and desired output of you XPath expression?

Comment: @Luuk there's no xml but I'll post the part of the source code of the excel after it converts and the desired out put.